# Setup several jquery dialogs in one asp.net mvc html file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

In my Index view I have a Create and Open template link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create Template", "JsonCreate", "Template", new { id = "CreateTemplate" })
@Html.ActionLink("Open Template", "JsonOpen", "Template", new { id = "OpenTemplate" })

<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 300,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Create Template',
            hide: "fade",         
            show: "fade",
            modal: true,
            open: function(event, ui) {               
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("Create")");
            },
            buttons: {
             "Save": function () {                      
                        var form = $('form', this);
                        $(form).submit();
                     },
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }); 

        $('#OpenTemplate').click(function ()
        {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $('#CreateTemplate').click(function ()
        {
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

For the Open template link I want a pretty different dialog:

- other buttons
- other size
- other title
- etc...

What do I have to change that my open template link can open its own dialog using the same dialog div "#dialog"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried re-using a single div for multiple different dialogs in the past and I highly recommend just creating a new div and a new instance of ui.dialog. It adds additional html at the bottom of the body tag, but this is a small price to pay for the benefit of clearly separating the javascript code. If you need different HTML inside the dialog div then there is absolutely no reason not to **use two completely separate divs**. Doing so will save you significant time and mental anguish.

Should you choose not to heed this advice, I would recommend creating two config objects and destroying the dialog instance on close. Something like this:

```
$(function () {
    var baseConfig = {
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        hide: "fade",
        show: "fade",
        modal: true,
        close: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy');
        },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                var form = $('form', this);
                $(form).submit();
            },
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    }
    var createConfig = {
        width: 300,
        title: 'Create Template',
        open: function(event, ui) {               
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Create")");
        }
    }
    var openConfig = {
        width: 500,
        title: 'Open Template',
        open: function(event, ui) {               
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("Open")");
        }
    }

    $('#OpenTemplate').click(function ()
    {
        var config = $.extend(baseConfig, openConfig);
        $('#dialog').dialog(config);
        return false;
    });

    $('#CreateTemplate').click(function ()
    {
        var config = $.extend(baseConfig, createConfig);
        $('#dialog').dialog(createConfig);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is just one solution. There may be other ways to do this without destroying the dialog, but trust me when I say this will be much cleaner. Again, this div re-use solution assumes that the HTML inside the div **does not change** at all.

Comment: hm maybe I am wrong or too unexperienced in that area, but my html changes because the html for open a template is different to create a template. But due to your opinion/experiences which I can fully understand how would you setup all the code with 2 different divs? My question might look dumb... but actually later I have 5 of those dialogs in one index view setting up 5 hidden divs is this the way to go?

Comment: I guess if you are dynamically loading the HTML for all 5 of those divs it wouldn't matter if you re-used the same #dialog div 5 times. You might still want 5 separate config objects though.

Comment: did you try your code? Using it and no buttons in the dialogs are visible?? although the animation (fade) is not played anymore. I guess there are some typos with the config variable...

Comment: have done now about 20 dialogs I must admit you are right. Its better to not reuse a dialog object because the old partial view could be loaded (as it was in my case), old validation errors are still visible etc...